# Using Reversediff in Julia throws a weird type error that I don't understand

Tags: julia, automatic-differentiation

I have the following function

```
error = prior_error(data,s_vals,ones(20)/20)
```

This executes fine.  I now package the arguments up as follows

```
inputs = (data,s_vals,ones(20)/20)
```

And then try and get the gradient

```
test = gradient(prior_error,inputs)
```

Using the `gradient` function from the ReverseDiff package.  The type signature of the arguments for the `prior_error` function is as follows

```
prior_error(data::Matrix,sample_vals::Vector,prior::Vector)
```

But I am getting the following error when I try and get that gradient

```
MethodError: no method matching prior_error(::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 2, Matrix{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}, ::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}, ::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}})

ReverseDiff.GradientTape(::Function, ::Tuple{Matrix{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}, ::ReverseDiff.GradientConfig{Tuple{ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 2, Matrix{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}, ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}, ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}})@tape.jl:207
gradient(::Function, ::Tuple{Matrix{Float64}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}, ::ReverseDiff.GradientConfig{Tuple{ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 2, Matrix{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}, ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}, ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}})@gradients.jl:22
top-level scope@Local: 5
```

I'm afraid, being relatively new to both Julia and the ReverseDiff package in Julia, I don't even know where to start trying to solve this error.  Any advice on how to fix would be greatly appreciated!

### UPDATE

I figured out its because I'm assigning too strict a type signature, so actually leaving the functions without a type signature allows the autodiff to progress UNTIL I try and do a matrix multiplication, and I get this error

```
MethodError: *(::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 2, Matrix{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}, ::LinearAlgebra.Diagonal{ReverseDiff.TrackedReal{Float64, Float64, ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}, ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64, Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Float64}}}) is ambiguous. Candidates:

*(A::AbstractMatrix, D::LinearAlgebra.Diagonal) in LinearAlgebra at /home/peter/julia-1.7.3/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/LinearAlgebra/src/diagonal.jl:222

*(x::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{V, D, 2}, y::AbstractMatrix) where {V, D} in ReverseDiff at /home/peter/.julia/packages/ReverseDiff/GtPeW/src/derivatives/linalg/arithmetic.jl:213

*(x::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{V, D, 2}, y::AbstractArray) where {V, D} in ReverseDiff at /home/peter/.julia/packages/ReverseDiff/GtPeW/src/derivatives/linalg/arithmetic.jl:213

*(x::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{V, D}, y::AbstractMatrix) where {V, D} in ReverseDiff at /home/peter/.julia/packages/ReverseDiff/GtPeW/src/derivatives/linalg/arithmetic.jl:213

*(A::AbstractMatrix, B::AbstractMatrix) in LinearAlgebra at /home/peter/julia-1.7.3/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/LinearAlgebra/src/matmul.jl:151

*(x::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{V, D}, y::AbstractArray) where {V, D} in ReverseDiff at /home/peter/.julia/packages/ReverseDiff/GtPeW/src/derivatives/linalg/arithmetic.jl:213

Possible fix, define

*(::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{V, D, 2}, ::LinearAlgebra.Diagonal) where {V, D}
```

But I don't understand what this means.  Am I literally writing out a function with that type signature?  Do I need to manually code in a function for matrix multiplication?

Comment: Unfortunately these ambiguities are hard to avoid, as `*` has so many methods, it's a problem with the TrackedMatrix idea. You can try to define a method [like these](https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ReverseDiff.jl/blob/master/src/derivatives/linalg/arithmetic.jl#L195) with the given signature, and `record_mul` there will handle things further. Opening an issue at ReverseDiff would also be a good idea.